# Cómo hacer un link desde un Newsletter a la sección de una App

Tags: html, sql, android, ios, app

muy buen día.
Trabajo en una empresa que está renovando su app, la verdad estamos muy verdes en esto, y me piden hacer que desde un newsletter al buzón del móvil del cliente se pueda linkear un tema a una sección de nuestra app (que ya tendría descargada el cliente)

Mis problemas son:
a) ¿Se puede linkear directo a una sección?
b) ¿Hay forma de hacer un sólo link que pueda detectar el sistema operativo del dispositivo o debo utilizar dos ligas (una para Ios y otra para Android)?
Saludos y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que ya resolvisteis la duda, pero te respondo a grandes rasgos por si a alguien le resulta de utilidad.
Se necesita implementar tanto el IOS como en Android la capacidad para detectar DEEPLINKS, es decir, en ambos códigos necesitas configurar una url por ejemplo:

http://nombre_de_la_app.es (es la que publica tu app para que el dispositivo "sepa" que debe intentar abrir la aplicación en el caso de que esté instalada)

http://nombre_de_la_app.es/ruta_específica_para_navegar_a_una_pantalla_determinada
(al abrir la app se le pasa la ruta específica pudiendo así conocer qué navegación debe realizar al poner la aplicación en primer plano)

El sufijo de la url suele ser algo ilegible, como H3hWfh9h3Fv por temas de seguridad, lo defines tu junto con el equipo que genere el deeplink.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.